# How to run scripts in index.html in react if you don't have index.html

Tags: javascript, html, node.js, reactjs, scrypt

I am still new to React.
I have React web App to which I need to add several scripts.
Although scripts have to be inside of body tag in `index.html`.
Like this :

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
  <head>
    <title>React example</title>
    <meta charset="UTF-8" />
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1" />
    <style media="only screen">
      html,
      body,
      #root {
        height: 100%;
        width: 100%;
      }
    </style>
  </head>
  <body>
    <div id="root">Loading React example&hellip;</div>
      <script 
        src="https://unpkg.com/systemjs@0.19.39/dist/system.src.js"
       > 
       </script>
      <script src="systemjs.config.js"></script>
      <script>
        System.import('./index.jsx').catch(function(err) {
          console.error(err);
        });
      </script>
  </body>
</html>
```

But the problem is that my app doesn't have `index.html` it has only `index.js`.
I tried to add this script with `document.write` but I think it's a wrong way of doing it.
Besides that i have Semantic and Syntactic errors which I cannot understand they are also attached [here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/S63Yh.png)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can append the scripts in your react code with:

```
let script = document.createElement("script");
script.setAttribute("src", scriptUrl);
script.setAttribute("type", "text/javascript");
```

(this is for linked scripts, but embedded scripts can be done in a similar way)

Comment: Hi @Judith  thank you for answer.
And  could you please tell if i use embedded scrypts i should pass the source code into 
like this script.setAttribute("src", sourceCodeOfScrypt); with "src" ?

Comment: it should be `script.innerHTML =  'source as string'`

Answer (score 0):

Hi I used this in my react application
I inserted dynamic yandex metrica code

Возможно поможет кому то вставить код Яндекс метрики в SPA ReactJs App динамически, код счетчика я получаю с бекенда

```
export function addCustomScriptAndHtmlInHead(tagString: string ): void {
    const range = document.createRange()
    range.selectNode(document.getElementsByTagName('BODY')[0])
    const documentFragment = range.createContextualFragment(tagString)
    document.head.appendChild(documentFragment)
}
```